# Error escaping single quote around parameter

Tags: postgresql, jdbctemplate

I'm getting an error while attempting to escape a single quote around a parameter using jdbctemplate and postgresql. This is the native query I'm trying to run:

```
Select table.date from table where date > current_timestamp - interval '7 day'
```

The '7' is the parameter where the '?' goes.

I've attempted to use two single quotes, but I still receive an error message saying: The column index is out of range

I have also attempted to use double question marks ?? instead of ?, but that doesn't work either.

`Select table.date from table where date > current_timestamp - interval '? day'`

Is what I am trying to achieve. Advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, posting here for any future readers:

```
Select table.date from table where date > current_timestamp - CAST (? AS INTERVAL))
```

Comment: Provided that you're adding the `'day'` part in Java, the default units for an `interval` are, AFAIK, seconds. A closer equivalent to your original would be `cast(? || 'day' as interval)`.

Comment: Yes, good point, I should've mentioned that I was adding the 'day' in java.